# NativeScript Slider step

Tags: nativescript

I am using a slider widget in my NativeScript app and I was wondering if there is a step property.  In my case the widget represents money and I want to slide in increments of $5.

I looked at the documentation, but could not find anything that helps in this scenario.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing to set the slider to increment in groups of 5; but that isn't really needed to do what you want.   All you have to do is do:

```
var yourDisplayValue = "$"+(slider.value * 5);
```

Depending on what you are doing, you can create an observable, put both the slider value and the display value as observable variables.  Attach a function to the observable onchange event; then automatically update your displayvalue when the slider value changes.   Then you just display the display value...

Comment: Thanks @Nathanael,  I was hoping that there was some obscure property that allows to do that without having to go through all the hoops of managing the value manually, but, I guess not :)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else has the same issue, I did the following (using @Nathanael's suggestion):

```js
model.customer.addEventListener(Observable.propertyChangeEvent, function(data) {
  if (data.propertyName.toString() == 'amount') {
    var v = ceil(model.customer.amount);
    var m = (5 - (v % 5)) + v;
    model.customer.set('amount_display', m);
  }
});
```

The slider is bound to amount and I have a label bound to amount_display.

This function can be used to create a "step"-like functionality for any amount, just replace 5 with any other number.

Comment: `var m = (5 - (v % 5)) + v - 5;` I have to add the "-5" to respect the min and max values.